# UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden Crashing App On iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

My application support is iPad only.
I have UISplitViewController in it.

Left Menu

- `UIViewController`

  - `UITableView`

    - `UITableViewCell`
    - `UILabel` (Added UITapGestureRecognizer)
    - `UIImageView`

Center View

- `UIViewController`

  - `UIView`

I'm Showing the popover when user taps on UserName label (Left menu -> Tableview -> Cell -> Label)

So my code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is below.

```
__weak LeftMenuUserTCell *weakCell = cell;
        cell.didTapProfileOption = ^{
            NSLog(@"Option Tapped");

            [self showMyProfilePopupFrom:weakCell.lblUserName inView:weakCell.lblUserName.superview];
        };
```

and i'm presenting popover like this

```
-(void)showMyProfilePopupFrom:(UIView *)sourceView inView:(UIView *)parentView
{
    ListViewController *listView=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ListViewController"];
    listView.listDelegate=self;

    NSArray *optionList=@[@"My Profile",@"Change Password",@"Sign Out"];

    listView.dataArray=[optionList mutableCopy];
    listView.selectedItemIndex = -1;
    listView.listType = 1;



        listView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
        UIPopoverPresentationController *popover = listView.popoverPresentationController;
        listView.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 150);
        //popover.delegate = self;
        popover.sourceView = sourceView;
        popover.sourceRect = sourceView.bounds;
        popover.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
        [self presentViewController:listView animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Till now everything is working fine.
Now I have to keep hidden left menu by default so i wrote following code in `AppDelegate` where i'm setting up `UISplitViewController`.

```
self.rootSplitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden;
```

Now **Problem is my app is crashing** when i tap the mentioned label. I have checked that my application is even not crashing when i comment out the above line  (`UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden`).

Following is the crash log :

> MyApp[785:371642] invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to
>   CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on
>   _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.
>
> MyApp[785:371642] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary
>   initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from
>   objects[0]'

Testing on iPad Air (iOS 10.3.3)

Comment: Do you know on what line your app is crashing? Try setting an Exception Breakpoint, if you haven't done so already to help you with that.

Comment: @Koen when i write `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden` app is crashing otherwise everything is fine.

Comment: Yes, but the crash is actually happening somewhere else. It’s related to a dictionary (see the error). An exception breakpoint can help you determine where.